# Specific adaptive design of WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, adaptive-design, wpf-grid

I need to tune parameters of elements in the specific way but there's some cunning trick logic, which I can't implement yet.

Let me please draw a picture. On this picture black border is the Window's border, blue lines mean Grid, and yellow ones mean Textboxes which are taking all free space of cells.

[image]

Comment: please show your `xaml`  ?

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you want... do you expect scrollbars to appear for both textboxes because the 2nd is already taking so much space or what?

Comment: Basically, the WPF layout is mainly demand and constraint driven and doesn't really care for history. So, the grid will ask each of its cells for their desired space and then it will assign some space to each cell. But it will not really consider previous space assignments to adjust its current layout decision.